# What is the most efficient algorithm to find the closest prime less than a given number n?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

**Problem**
Given a number n, 2<=n<=2^63. n could be prime itself. Find the prime p that is closest to n.

Using the fact that for all primes p, p>2, p is odd and p is of the form 6k+1 or 6k+5, one could write a loop from n−1 to 2 to check if that number is prime. So instead of checking for all numbers I need to check for every odd of the two forms above. However, I wonder if there is a faster algorithm to solve this problem? i.e. some constraints that can restrict the range of numbers need to be checked? Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that 6k+1 and 6k+5 are both *always* odd for integer k.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Did I mention it above? Or I misunderstood your instruction?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant. You said "every odd of the two forms above", which could imply that one or both are not always odd. I think you've got it right, it's just that English leaves room for ambiguity at every opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality, the odds of finding a prime number are "high" so brute force checking while skipping "trivial" numbers (numbers divisible by small primes) is going to be your best approach given what we know about number theory to date.

*[update] A mild optimization that you might do is similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes where you define some small smooth bound and mark all numbers in a range about N as being composite and only test the numbers relatively prime to your smooth base. You will need to make your range and smoothness small enough as to not eclipse the runtime of the comparatively "expense" prime test.*

Answer (score 2):

The biggest optimization that you can do is to use a fast primality check before doing a full test.  For instance see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test for a commonly used test that will quickly eliminate most numbers as "probably not prime".  Only after you have good reason to believe that a number is prime should you attempt to properly prove primality.  (For many purposes people are happy to just accept that if it passes a fixed number of trials of the Rabin-Miller test, it is so likely to be prime that you can just accept that fact.)